# Sometimes Crash when trying to delete the row from UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

First of all it works fine if i delete the row with a single swipe. Unfortunately whenever i'm just playing around with it without deleting it gets crashed. This is how i'm deleting my rows:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


        if editingStyle == .delete {

            viewModel.deleteFromHistory(indexPath: indexPath, completion: {

                self.viewModel.history.remove(at: indexPath.item)
                self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)

            })

        }

    }
```

And the crash message:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'No occurrence for index
>   path (null)'

Comment: is your aray name viewmodel?

Comment: its "history" under viewModel

Comment: You should set the debugger to break when throwing an exception. That will show you the exact line where the error occurs. Without that information, it's pretty difficult to guess at what the reason might be.

Comment: indexPath.item !! It is indexPath.row for a UITableView

Comment: that's not the issue here @Nitish

Comment: What does the `deleteFromHistory` method do?

Comment: it deletes data from coredata

Answer (score 1):

You are using indexPath in completion block. So indexPath in completion block and in the argument of method `deleteFromHistory` may not be the same.

- Add exception debug and try to check the value for indexPath.

Answer (score 0):

Error contains some hint, I think :) before call code which deletes data from your history and cells from table you must to ensure that indexpath isn't nil.

Try to check it, I hope it will help.